# Do self-invoking functions work in IE strict-mode?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I tested the following code:

```
$(function () {
    "use strict"
    (function () {
        console.log("something");
    }());
});
```

but when run in IE, I keep getting an exception: "Function Expected". In Firefox this works fine. This seems like basic, functionality. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does adding a semicolon after the "use strict" string help? (Also, are you sure you've imported jQuery?)

Comment: I'm not sure if it will make a difference, but I always use a different syntax for this.  `(function () {})()`

Comment: Which IE version are you using?

Comment: Huh, the semi-colon thing worked. Post that as an answer (and why it works if you could)

Comment: @sircodesalot: Your code is being interpreted as `"blah"(function () {}());` (i.e, you're trying to "execute" the string "blah" as if it was a function, passing the return value of your IIFE (i.e. `undefined`) as a parameter).

Comment: FYI, in Firefox 22, it throws the error `TypeError: "use strict" is not a function` for me. In Chrome as well. So it's not an IE problem.

Comment: Runs fine in firefox 20.0.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules of automatic semicolon insertion are pretty bizarre. It's a hotly-contested point whether to code in a way that takes advantage of that feature, so I won't get into that, but in this case what's happening is that the parser thinks that you may be trying to call a function.  Adding a semicolon after the string should fix that.

Another thing you could try:

```
$(function () {
    "use strict"
    !function () {
        console.log("something");
    }();
});
```

(Personally I'd just add the semicolon :-)

Comment: +1. Any ideas why this works in Firefox and not IE? Shouldn't this behavior be explicitly specified in the spec?

Comment: @FelixKling, ah. I guess the OP being mistaken about it working in Firefox could be another reason why it "works" in Firefox but not in IE ;).

Comment: I just ran it again, and it works fine in firefox (V 20.0.1)?

Comment: Also, what does the "!" signify?

Comment: @sircodesalot: It's the unary boolean not operator. `!false` returns `true` and vice versa. In this case it has the same purpose as the parenthesis you originally had: To treat the function definition as function *expression* (not as function *declaration*). But unlike the parenthesis it cannot be mistakenly interpreted as function call. One could use any other unary operator instead, like `+` or `typeof`. The operator does not matter, only the effect it has on how the code is interpreted matters.